# multi-region deployment in Azure using ARM

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager

I am performing multi-region deployment in Azure using ARM. The only approach I could find so far is by using *copy* operation as explained [here](https://alexandrebrisebois.wordpress.com/2015/06/03/create-multi-geo-environments-using-azure-resource-manager/)
However, in the beginning of the post author wrote that *some of you might think that it’s not such great idea, and I can appreciate that*.

Why is that? What could be alternative to *copy* function? What is ‘official’ recommendation from MSFT to implement multi-region deployment in ARM?

Comment: I think it's a good idea. I can't see why you wouldn't do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know of a single best practice recommendation here but there are a few other things you can think about for the scenario.  If you think of a resource group as a management boundary, then having everything in the same resource group may not be ideal.  For example if you wanted to tear down one region and rebuild it, this is much more complicated within a single resource group.  If you wanted to simply add a new region, while you could do this with the same template and an incremental deployment, it's faster and maybe cleaner in a separate deployment.  If you wanted to assign permissions based on region, again more complicated.

OTOH, if you deploy each region into it's own resource group, this becomes much easier to manage.  The only difference is then that the copy loops aren't needed in the template and you do multiple deployments of the same template (to each region).

Again, no hard/fast rule, but some ways to think about it...

Comment: Thanks for your advice. We followed similar approach: instead of relying on `copy` function, we have parametrized ARM with `location` param and triggering several deployments in a row by `ResourceManagementClient.deployments.create_or_update(..)` Python Azure SDK.